# OpenGL FrameBuffer and glViewport

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

I am going through a render pass onto a FrameBufferObject such that I can use the result as a texture in the next rendering pass. Looking at tutorials, I need to call:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_TEXTURE2D, mFrameBufferObjectID);
glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
```

where mWidth and mHeight are the width and height of the frame buffer object. It seems without this glViewport call, nothing gets drawn correctly. What's strange is that upon starting the next frame, I need to call:

```
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
```

so that I can go back to my previous width/height of the window; but calling it seems to only render my stuff at half of the original window size. So I physically only see a quarter of my screen gets stuff rendered onto (yes the entire scene is on it). I tried putting a break point and looking at the width and heigh values, they are the original values (1024, 640). Why is this happening? I tried doubling those and it correctly draws on my entire window.

I'm doing this on Mac via xcode and with glew.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code you didn't show.

Comment: Is this a Mac with a retina screen? You might have a mixup between resolutions in logical pixels and actual physical pixels on screen. Or whatever the correct terminology is...

Comment: Yes, I'm using this on Mac xcode.

Comment: On a Mac with a retina display, the frame buffer is larger than the window by 2x in each dimension. Your glViewport call with window_width and window_height needs to be adjusted for the screen. If you use glfw, this is how you retrieve them: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_fbsize

Answer (score 1):

The viewport settings are stored in the global state. So if you change it, it stays at the new values until you call `glViewport` again. As you already noted, you'll have to set the size whenever you want to render to a FBO (or backbuffer) that has a different size then the previously bound one.

Comment: My problem is that after say calling glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024) to render a fbo, I want to restore the viewport to the screen which has the resolution of (1024, 680). Calling glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 680) only renders a quarter of the screen, not the full screen.

Comment: I see. Please exactly show the order in which you execute the commands. The correct place to reset the viewport would be directly before drawing to screen.

Comment: I looked over everything again and again. It really seems that glViewport(0, 0, X, Y) gives me X/2 and Y/2 width and height of the window. Perhaps this is Mac's "high resolution" pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the scissor box as well as the viewport if you have the scissor test enabled using

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

To fix your problem write

```
glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
glScissor(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
```

and

```
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
glScissor(0, 0, window_width, window_height);
```

everytime when you switch to a new framebuffer with a different size as the previous one, or always just to be safe.

See this link of the reference [glScissor](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/docbook4/xhtml/glScissor.xml)
Or this other post explaining the purpose of it https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40704/what-is-the-purpose-of-glscissor

Comment: Thank you friend - this helped me, with frame buffer size different from the screen; I forgot to update the viewport each time I bound/unbound. Obvious now...